# Extracting data elegantly from a string in C++?

Tags: c++, regex

I may have the following inputs:

```
  <Object::1 <1,2><3,4><3,3>>          
  <Object::2 <1,2><3,4>>
  <Object::3 <1,2> 5>
```

I need two extract the value after :: (may be a string), and then the i number of values after in the <>.

So for the first example, I'd want to get:

1   <1,2>   <3,4>   <3,3>

I can read from the string, I'm just not sure how to get what I want from it?

Comment: *"and then the i number of values after in the <>"* - What does this mean?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Look at case 3.

Comment: if these tuples can be arbitrarily nested, I'd consider writing a proper grammar/parser

Comment: Edit your question to show the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, let's first read the input line into a string.

```
std::string text_from_file;  
getline(my_text_file, text_from_file);
```

You want to "skip" past the text "
This involves using the `find` method of `std::string`.

```
std::string::size_type position_in_string;
position_in_string = text_from_file.find("<Object::");
```

Next, test the position.  After all, we don't want to continue if the key string wasn't found.

```
if (position_in_string != std::string::npos)
{
```

The next tricky part is to get the number following the "::".
This can be done many ways, we'll try `std::istringstream`.
We need to get the text out of the string after the "::", which is called a *substring*, abbreviated as `substr`.

```
unsigned int quantity = 0;
std::istringstream string_input(text_from_file.substr(position_in_string));
```

We can use the stream extraction operators on the text string:

```
string_input >> quantity;
```

Getting the remaining text from the input text is called parsing.  Very similar to the operations above.  You give it a try.

There are many posts in StackOverflow that can be very helpful.  Find them by searching for "[C++] parsing read from file".

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you `(?<=::)([^<]+)\s+.*?(<.*)>` [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kC1wF8)

Comment: You should mention that you are providing a regular expression.  Also recommend how to use that regular expression, including pre C11 versions.